# How to define LaTeX like environment in plain TeX?

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

How do I define LaTeX like environment using TeX primitives? I have just started learning TeX using Knuth's TeX book and found it hard to implement the LaTeX like environment using TeX primitives. An example of the environment I am talking about is `\begin{document} ... \end{document}`. Are environments implemented like `\def\begin#1\end#1{some conditional statement..}`?

Comment: Just wondering here, if you're using plain tex, why do you want to reinvent latex?

Comment: @daleif I am just really curious how it is all implemented... looking for the concepts here because I cannot comprehend the source code of the LaTeX package installed on my computer...

Comment: You could just copy the definitions of `\begin` and `\end` from [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co)...

Comment: @Werner I kinda see how it is implemented. I think I need to learn more TeX to get a full grasp of what is going on. Thank you.

Comment: Victor Eijkhout's TeX by Topic discusses environments. Also, if you look in the source file of the TeXbook (texbook.tex) and the macros file (manmac.tex) you can see examples of `\begin` and `\end` constructions.

Comment: Exercise 5.7 in the TeXbook. But for a `document` environment you need to avoid grouping: having the whole document inside a group might have a bad impact on memory when big documents are dealt with.

Answer (score 6):

The basic idea is that `\begin{foo}` executes `\foo` and `\end{foo}` executes `\endfoo`  all within a `\begingroup..\endgroup` group.

So ignoring error checking (and newly added environment hooks etc) a plain tex implementation would be as follows, I renamed begin and end to avoid clashing with the `\end` primitive (which LaTeX renames to `\@@end`)

```
% define environment syntax
\def\zbegin#1{\begingroup\csname#1\endcsname}
\def\zend#1{\csname end#1\endcsname\endgroup}

% a sample environment
\def\table#1{\halign\bgroup#1\cr}
\def\endtable{\crcr\egroup}


\zbegin{table}{\hfil#\quad&#\hfil}
rrr&lll\cr
1&2\cr
33&44
\zend{table}

\bye
```

[image]